# BigDecimal - how to do this calculation in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have ..

target = targetmax / difficulty

targetmax = 26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960

difficulty = 14484.162361

target = 26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960 / 14484.162361

target = 1861311315012765306929610463010191006516769515973403833769533170

So I attempted this in Java as

```
    double difficulty = 14484.162361;

    String targetmaxStr = "26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960";

    BigDecimal targetmaxd = new BigDecimal(targetmaxStr);

    BigDecimal difficultyd = new BigDecimal(difficulty);

    BigDecimal targetd = targetmaxd.divide(difficultyd, MathContext.DECIMAL128); 

    System.out.println("target : " + targetD);
```

It prints

target : 1.861311315012765229690386592708552E+63

I am really expecting value:

target = 1861311315012765306929610463010191006516769515973403833769533170

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I really believe that it is.  The discrepancy is caused by the use of the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor - which is what that other question addresses.

Comment: You are right, it is a combination of issues.  Creating `difficulty` from a double is creating an inaccuracy as are the issues I pointed out in my answer.  I'll update my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems.

First, use `targetd.toPlainString())` to print the `BigDecimal` out avoiding scientific notation.

Second, you are limiting your precision too much by using `MathContext.DECIMAL128`.  Try something like `new MathContext(200)` instead.

Third, as was debated in the comments, creating your `BigDecimal` from a `double` creates some precision issues.  Create from a `String` instead to avoid those.

Here it is all together:

```
String targetmaxStr = "26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960";
BigDecimal targetmaxd = new BigDecimal(targetmaxStr);
BigDecimal difficultyd = new BigDecimal("14484.162361");
BigDecimal targetd = targetmaxd.divide(difficultyd, new MathContext(200)); 
System.out.println("target : " + targetd.toPlainString());
```

Result:

target : 1861311315012765306929610463010191006516769515973403833769533170.5181511669744807274464658288015444595719414139754270599065953124329244737606680298383048483144520034008751609022370030307892100271382756

Comment: Thank you Matthew, but somehow only first 15 digits are matching with answer and rest digits are not.

Comment: Did you compare with my update re: the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor?

Comment: Ah, that worked .. Thank you so much